# Configurar múltiplos Serviços Windows em um único projeto

Tags: c#, windows, services

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto do tipo Windows Services e me deparei com a necessidade de realizar rotinas com tempo de execução e regras distintas.

É possível ter múltiplos serviços windows em um único projeto?

Eu tentei o seguinte código mais sem sucesso, pois desta forma o exe sempre chama a primeira classe instanciada:

```
ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] {
  new ServiceEvento96(),
  new ServiceEvento17()
};

ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
```

Answer (score 0):

A solução para este caso é bem difícil de se encontrar, mas acho que consegui encontra-la [aqui](http://www.bryancook.net/2008/04/running-multiple-net-services-within.html), vou explicar para você.

**1º** - Crie uma classe `Installer`, ela deve ser publica, não estática, herdar de `Installer` e ser decorada com o atributo `RunInstaller` com parâmetro `true`.

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class MeuServicoInstaller : Installer
{
   public MeuServicoInstaller()
   {
     ServiceProcessInstaller processInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
     processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;

     ServiceInstaller mainServiceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();
     mainServiceInstaller.ServiceName = "Service1";
     mainServiceInstaller.Description = "Service One que faz tal coisa";
     mainServiceInstaller.ServicesDependedOn = new string [] { "Service2" };

     ServiceInstaller secondServiceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();
     secondServiceInstaller.ServiceName = "Service2";
     secondServiceInstaller.Description = "Service Two que faz tal coisa";

     Installers.Add(processInstaller);
     Installers.Add(mainServiceInstaller);
     Installers.Add(secondaryServiceInstaller);
   }
}
```

No construtor desta classe você adiciona seus serviços do modo que o exemplo mostra, atenção a linha que contém `ServicesDependedOn`, ali está dizendo que o `serviço 1` depende do `serviço 2`, por isso quando o primeiro for chamado, o segundo também será pois é dependente.

**2º** - Esta classe que você criou será invocada e instanciada quando você rodar o processo `InstallUtil.exe`.

**Obs.:** Atenção quanto aos nomes dos serviços, eles devem ser iguais. Aconselho até a usar a keyword `nameof` para manter a consistência de nomes ao invés de `strings`.

**Exemplos:**

`mainServiceInstaller.ServiceName = nameof(Service1);`

`mainServiceInstaller.ServicesDependedOn = new string [] { nameof(Service2) };`